# Change Table Name in linq query at runtime

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a simple query from linq but i want to change my table name that used in my query at run time.

```
    Dim DynamicTable = db.P_Ac_Accounts

    Dim ComBankValidPlaceAccess = From ValidPlace In DynamicTable
                                  Where ValidPlace.PlaceID = 1
                                  Select ValidPlace
```

this method work correctly but when i set the variable as a public variable i meet the error.
please help me about this problem

Comment: What type of LINQ provider is this about? That makes a big difference. Also, could you give some more context why you need to do this? I see an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269) lurking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i  have a same query for all of my tables,and want to change my table name, base of my forms tables, and in other side have an insert ,update button too that want to use it for all of forms.

Comment: I hope that doesn't mean that you've got a whole bunch of equally structured tables, which would indicate poor normalization. If it's for handling many different tables: that's a PIA in a statically typed environment. Dynamics, reflection and late binding all over the place. That's why for javascript they made typescript.

Comment: You can use dynamic linq : https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Thanks,i read about it in your site before but that's not my mention. i have PlaceId field in all of my table i only want to change my table name in run time by where of PlaceId filed

Comment: Actually i want to have public variable as table type and set my current sql table name to it.